# PostgreSQL Server doesn't listen: Tried everything and failed

Tags: postgresql, centos

When attempting to connect to PostgreSQL from a remote Windows server using pgAdmin 1.16.1 I get the dreaded 'Server doesn't listen' message with 'could not connect to server: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060) Is the server running on host "xxx.xx.xxx.xx" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432'.

I'm running PostgreSQL 9.3 on CentOS 6.4. Here's what I've tried so far:

- I can access the database locally with psql --username=postgres. The database is there, it's running and I can query it
- In postgresql.conf, I've set

  ```
  listen_addresses = '*'
  port = 5432
  ```
- In pg_hba.conf, I've got the server that I am trying to access the database from listed as:

  ```
  host    all             all             xxx.xx.xxx.0/24         md5
  ```
- SELinux is turned off (`getenforce` gets the response `Disabled`)
- Just in case I've added port 5432 to the IPTables

  ```
  iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5432 -j ACCEPT
  ```
- I've gone into postgresql with psql and set the password (although I'm convinced it was already set correctly)

  ```
  ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD '*************';
  ```
- Typing `netstat -an`gives these references to port 5432 (not sure they are relevant):

  ```
  Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State      
  tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      

  tcp        0      0 :::5432                     :::*                        LISTEN      

  Active UNIX domain sockets (servers and established)
  Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node Path
  unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     677454 /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432
  ```
- I can ping from the remote server to the database server
- I have no problem connecting to another server running PostgreSQL 9.1 on Ubuntu from the same remote server using the same installation of pgAdmin

I'm stumped. Does anyone have a clue to what more could be wrong? And yes, I did remember to restart the server after changing the config files. I believe that I've read every other post on the subject.

Comment: Do you see anything in the PostgreSQL server logs when you attempt a connection? If in doubt, fire up Wireshark and see what's happening on the network interface.

Comment: @CraigRinger The PostgreSQL server logs show nothing when I attempt to connect. Running `telnet xxx.xx.xxx.xx 5432` doesn't connect either, while `telnet xxx.xx.xxx.xx 22` does. Running `telnet localhost 5432` on the database server connects. Not sure how to interpret that. Still trying to grasp what Wireshark can do for me, but don't I need to install it on the database server - there is no Linux version as far as I can see.

Comment: Sounds like firewall. As for Wireshark, yes, there most certainly is a Linux version! Practically every distro has it packaged. `yum install wireshark-gnome` on Fedora; probably the same on CentOS.

Comment: Sorry, there's no GUI on my server. I have now further confirmed that I can access the database via ODBC from the database server itself. I think this pretty much narrows it down to a firewall issue. I'll get someone familiar with linux firewalls to have a look at it.

Comment: Good idea. Just FYI, there's a command-line-only wireshark too.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm having the same exact problem. I can connect locally but can't connect remotely. My config is just like what you had described.

Comment: When I had this issue, it is was because I wasn't paying attention and forgot to remove the `#` from the `listen_addresses` line.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you forgot add OUTPUT rule?

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 0/0 --sport 1024:65535 -d xx.xx.xx.xx  --dport 5432 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -s xx.xx.xx.xx --sport 5432 -d 0/0 --dport 1024:65535 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

xx.xx.xx.xx - your server IP
```

Comment: I have now added the output line, but still no luck.

Comment: @MiG62: use `iptables -nvL` to see what rules are matched. Rules added with `iptables -A ...` as shown are ineffective if there are REJECT/DROP rules that counter them upwards in the chain.